# Time function that checks for certain days

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, time

I have the following time function that I use to output if the business is open or closed. The way I have it coded works fine for normal business weeks. What I am wanting to do is program it for holidays, such as Christmas, 4th of July, etc that are always on the same day, so the output shows we are closed.

How would I program in the fixed holidays?

```
function timeNow() {

    //Get time
    var d = new Date(),
    h = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
    m = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    //Get Day
    new Date().getDay();
    var day = new Date().getDay();
    console.log(day);
    var operateDay = '';
    if (day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
        operateDay = true;
    } else if (day < 1 || day > 5) {
        operateDay = false;
    }

    // Checking time range
    var operatingTime = ((h >= 8 && h < 17) || (h === 8 && m == 0));
    var closedTime = (h >= 17 || h <= 8);
    var operateStatus = '';

    if ((operatingTime) && (operateDay = true)) {
        operateStatus = 'Our office is currently open';
        $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
        $('#operationStatus').addClass('open');
    } else if (closedTime) {
        operateStatus = 'Our office is currently closed';
        $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
        $('#operationStatus').addClass('closed');
    } else if (operateDay = false) {
        operateStatus = 'Our office is currently closed';
        $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
        $('#operationStatus').addClass('closed');
    }

    return operateStatus;
}
var operation = timeNow();
$('#operationStatus').html(operation);
```

Comment: Speaking just conceptually, I would imagine an array of the days to force to be closed, potentially already as Date objects, and then you could perform logic on that array to check and see if the date is the same as any of the array dates.  If so, the place is closed.

Comment: @Taplar I am not sure how to specify a day.

Comment: Ex. `new Date('07-01-2018')` would be July 1st

Comment: @Taplar `new Date('2018-07-01')` might yield better results, and you'd get best results with `new Date(2018, 6, 1)`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan `new Date('2018-07-01')` in the console evaluates to `Sat Jun 30 2018` which surprised me as I thought Date would expect ISO, but that is why I reversed the order.

Comment: @Taplar It's that date, at midnight, in UTC. You're probably on the wrong side of the divide, as am I. `new Date('2018-07-01T00:00:00')` makes it midnight local time.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your original function and created **an initial version**, that handles a custom, easily "configurable", human-readable list of specific holidays.

```js
/**
 * Returns the office's open/closed state.
 *
 * @param {Date} [time] - A custom Date object to override the current time.
 * @returns {string} The state of the office (open or closed).
 */
function timeNow(time) {
  // Holidays - month-day format, it's adjusted for human-readability, so
  // January is 1, February is 2 ... December is 12
  var holidays = [
    '01-01', // New Year's Day
    '07-04', // Independence Day,
    '11-11', // Veterans Day
    '12-25', // Chirstmas
    '12-31', // New Year's Eve
  ];
  
  // Possibility of overriding the current date, if needed
  time = time || new Date();

  // Get time
  var d = time,
    h = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
    m = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

  // Get day
  var day = time.getDay();
  var operateDay = '';
  if (day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
    operateDay = true;
  } else if (day < 1 || day > 5) {
    operateDay = false;
  }
  
  // Checking time range
  var operatingTime = ((h >= 8 && h < 17) || (h === 8 && m == 0));
  var closedTime = (h >= 17 || h <= 8);
  var operateStatus = '';

  // Check against holidays if the store is seemingly open  
  // Since in JavaScipt's built-in Date object, January is 0, February is 1 ... December is 11,
  // to be humanly usable, add 1 to it, hence the name "adjusted"
  var adjustedMonth = time.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayOfMonth = time.getDate();
    
  if (operatingTime) {
    for (var i = 0, len = holidays.length, holiday, holidayMonth, holidayDay; i < len; i++) {
      // Process the specific holiday month-date format
      holiday = holidays[i].split('-');
      holidayMonth = parseInt(holiday[0], 10);
      holidayDay = parseInt(holiday[1], 10);
      
      // Check, whether today is a holiday ...
      if (adjustedMonth === holidayMonth && dayOfMonth === holidayDay) {
        // ...and if it is, then ...Hooray! Hooray! It's a Holi-Holiday
        operatingTime = false;
        closedTime = true;
        break;
      }      
    }
  }

  if ((operatingTime) && (operateDay = true)) {
    operateStatus = 'Our office is currently open';
    $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
    $('#operationStatus').addClass('open');
  } else if (closedTime) {
    operateStatus = 'Our office is currently closed';
    $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
    $('#operationStatus').addClass('closed');
  } else if (operateDay = false) {
    operateStatus = 'Our office is currently closed';
    $('#closedWrap').addClass('block');
    $('#operationStatus').addClass('closed');
  }

  return operateStatus;
}

// Testing
var shouldBeOpen = [
  '2018-06-25',
  '2018-06-26',
  '2018-06-27',
  '2018-06-28',
  '2018-06-29'
];

var shouldBeClosed = [
  '2018-01-01',
  '2018-07-04',
  '2018-11-11',  
  '2018-12-25',  
  '2018-12-31',
  '2019-01-01'
];

var STATUS_OPEN = 'Our office is currently open';
var STATUS_CLOSED = 'Our office is currently closed';

// converts a human-readable year-month-day to UTC date
function strToUtcDate(string) {
  var parts = string.split('-');
  var year = parts[0];
  var month = parts[1];
  var day = parts[2];  
  return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, 12, 0, 0));
}

shouldBeOpen.forEach(function (string) {
  var date = strToUtcDate(string);
  var status = timeNow(date);
  
  if (status === STATUS_OPEN) {
    console.log('opened, as it should on:', date);
  } else {
    console.log('closed, BUT IT SHOULD NOT ON:', date);
  }
});

shouldBeClosed.forEach(function (string) {
  var date = strToUtcDate(string);
  var status = timeNow(date);
  
  if (status === STATUS_CLOSED) {
    console.log('closed, as it should on:', date);
  } else {
    console.log('opened, BUT IT SHOULD NOT ON:', date);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. This definitely helps out a lot. Is there a way that I could test this by changing the date to 7-4 and running it live?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, of course, but by live, I hope you mean staged on your server and not in production. Before you want to deploy it in any way, please use my modified source and **create a meaningful unit test suite**. I'm pretty sure there are egde cases, when it will return a false positive/negative.

Comment: How could I change the date? Because, updated my code with yours, but I think my output it solely just reading my returned function `return operateStatus;` to populate the output. You can view it here: http://test.mbkit.com/test.mbkit.com/contact

Comment: Please, use **only the `timeNow()` function** I've changed, not the whole sample with the quick-n-dirty tests and all. Change the date on your own computer for starter, but please, write some a proper unit test suite for your own sake.

Comment: Ok, so I just took out the other code except the timeNow() function. How do I manually change the date to reflect 7/4? I am new to the time/date functions.

Comment: I would fire up a **virtual machine**, change the date/time/timezone on that virtual machine to the desired date and check out in an actual real browser, whether the script works or not.

Comment: Alright, so I changed the way I got dates to this for testing `var day = new Date(2018,06,04);`. Initially I entered (2018, 07, 04), but then it read it as August. The panel is showing the business as open. Any ideas?